# Loading bar not loading

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

So I am writing a script and this is the script:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter
window=tkinter.Tk()
load=ttk.Progressbar(window, orient="horizontal",length="200",maximum="100", mode="determinate")
load.pack()
load.configure(value=0)
for int in range (0, 101):
    load.configure(value=int)
    window.title("{}%".format(int))
window.mainloop()
```

And so I want my progress bar to start a 0 and work it's way up but instead it starts by making the window and then it goes to 100 immediately.
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Your `for` loop has finished before `.mainloop` starts, what did you expect?

Comment: How does that affect the progress?

Comment: use `tkinter.after` to run every loop with delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `after` to call function with delay.

Besides you can't use long-running function because it stops mainloop which handle events and redraw all object on screen.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter

# ---

def update(value=0):
    # update 
    load.configure(value=value)
    window.title("{}%".format(value))

    if value < 100:
        # run again after 100ms (0.1s) with new value
        window.after(100, update, value+1)

# ---

window=tkinter.Tk()

load = ttk.Progressbar(window, orient="horizontal",length="200",maximum="100", mode="determinate")
load.configure(value=0)
load.pack()

# update(0) # run immediately
# run after 100ms (0.1s) with value=0
window.after(100, update, 0) 

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `after` adds function (`update`) and time (`100`) to special list and `mainloop` gets this function from this list after 100ms and calls it. Meanwhile `mainloop` can do other things - handle events, redraw widgets, etc. `update` changes progressbar value and use `after` to add `update` to the special list again. `mainloop` will call this function again - and this works like loop ("hidden loop")